# Assignment/scheduling how to formulate considering job time and job cost

Tags: modeling, scheduling, constraint-programming, assignment-problem

I have the following problem that I do not know how to formulate.
There are a fixed number of workers $w_i \in W$ for $i \in [1…N]$.
Also, there are a fixed number of jobs that must be assigned to each of the workers.
The set of jobs is $J$ and each job is $j_k$ for $k \in [1…M]$.
Each of the $j_k$ jobs span for a fixed number of days and requires a fixed number of hours each day. Also, the job is located at facility $f$.
There is a cost of transporting worker $w$ to facility $f$.
I want to assign/schedule the jobs and the workers while:

- The amount of job hours assigned to a particular worker cannot exceed a maximum per day.
- The whole job is assigned to the same worker (if a worker takes the job, he should finish it).
- Job overlapping is only possible if the two (or more) jobs is located at the same facility.
- Only certain workers can take certain jobs due to habilitations.

My goal is to minimize the cost of transporting.
I particularly don’t know how to formulate the assignment of hours to consecutive days given that job $j_k$ starts at any time (day).